# Facebook iOS SDK Test Tracking

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I updated the Facebook iOS SDK from version 3.8 to 3.13 and I would like to verify that install tracking is working using the following code:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

The app has already been installed on my device from a much earlier date/Facebook SDK ver 3.8. Is there anyway to verify I upgraded correctly? Not sure if reinstalling the app on my device will work since the install already occurred in the past.